# EPS figures are pixelized in the final PDF with LyX

Tags: lyx, eps, pixelated

This is the first time that I compile a LyX file with some EPS picture inside on my current computer. I already did that before on other computers, without any problem.

But here, the result is pixelized. All the document can be compiled, and is rendered nicely, but the EPS file is pixelized. I know it is not due to my EPS file which is really in vectorial format because I can open it with other readers and zoom inside without any problem.
Result :
[image]

I tried to figure out which options I should activate or which converter I have to set but didn't find anything.
This guy had the same problem than me : [Link](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=21751) but I think he is working on a Windows OS while I am on Mac OS, and the resolution don't seems to work for me.

EDIT : I tried for instance to set EPS to PDF (ps2pdf). The result is no longer pixelized but... takes the whole page, as a PS file. Here is an image of the result and the parameters :
[image]

EDIT again : Trying to use `epstopdf` is not working, image still pixelized, but maybe I don't use the correct parameters ? I was expecting something as 'PDF (epstopdf)' in the list but there is none of these.
[image]

Comment: Did you try opening the file with another pdf viewer?

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Comment: For the "whole page when converting" problem, you could try tools such as `pdfcrop`.

Comment: If it is a real EPS file with a correct bounding box, then `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` helps to get rid of the additional margins.

Comment: Since you are in a Mac, you can use `epstopdf` instead of `ps2pdf`, which produces the correct bounding box.

Comment: I installed the `epstopdf` package, then reconfigured LyX and so on. A new option for converting the image was in the list of converters, but it still don't work. Maybe wrong parameters...

Comment: Tried again and again, now it works ! I don't know what I did, maybe I din't reconfigured something correctly, I don't know, but now it's perfect ! Thanks @JLDiaz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the package `epstopdf` and to correctly configure the converter in LyX preferences. Then, reconfigure a bunch of times (it didn't work the first time...) but after doing the usual steps (quit and start the program again and so on) it worked. Thanks to JLDiaz for the answer !